# Taylor Series for Multivariables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Without finding the partial derivatives of $f\left(x,y\right)+e^x \cos (y)$, find the terms of up to and including order 4 in the Taylor series for f about (1,0).

I initially subbed in $y=0$ and tried to compute the Taylor series using the fact $$f(x,y)=f(1,0)+f_x(1,0)(y-0)+1/2! \cdot\ldots,$$ where I assumed all derivatives would equal $e$, but I now think is incorrect. How would I approach this question?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables

Comment: Still a bit confused i understand the example shown (of order 2) on this wiki, but when i carried on my calculations to order 4, my answer was incorrect. An explanantion to my question would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the $1$-variable Taylor polynomials of degree $4$ for the functions $e^x$ and $\cos(y)$ (and then discarding terms with total degree $>4$)?